# Too long path exception raised to a specific version of a package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I built my private Nuget repository on Azure free app service.
And I added the url into Visual Studio 2015.

There is a package having three versions 1.0.3~1.0.5.

The problem is only 1.0.3 version of the package will be successfully installed.
Others are always failed due to the exception (Too long path or file name).

I don't know why they show me different results.

Non of settings are different.
Also I placed the project folder on the root of D: drive.

Please see the log and let me know the reason :D

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' with respect to project 'TestApps\EntitiesTestConsole', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
Gathering dependency information took 52.53 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5'
Resolved actions to install package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5'
Retrieving package 'GEPAEntities 1.0.5' from 'P-ful, Inc.'.
  GET http://pfulnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/package/gepaentities/1.0.5
  OK http://pfulnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/package/gepaentities/1.0.5 63ms
Installing GEPAEntities 1.0.5.
Error downloading 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' from 'http://pfulnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/package/gepaentities/1.0.5'.
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' does not exist in project 'EntitiesTestConsole'
Package 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' does not exist in folder 'D:\GEPAClient\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 803.27 ms
Error downloading 'GEPAEntities.1.0.5' from 'http://pfulnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/package/gepaentities/1.0.5'.
  The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
========== Finished ==========
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.2133955
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I resolved my problem.

I just added supported framework versions into nuspec file.

```
  <dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" >
        ...
    </group>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" >
        ...
    </group>          
</dependencies>
```

Anyway it is working that I expected.